# GCC Attribute Syntax

Tags: c++, gcc, attributes, variable-declaration

Is there any difference between the following attribute syntaxes?

```
char a[N] __attribute__ ((aligned(X)));
char __attribute__ ((aligned(X))) b[N];
char (__attribute__ ((aligned(X))) c)[N];
```

If there is a difference, which represents "an X-aligned array of chars" and which represents "an array of X-aligned chars"? If there is no difference, which is the "correct" (or most common) way of writing it?

Likewise, does the answer to the above differ in the case of functions and function types?